# wirecloud / fiware "Not registered callback" although callback function is implemented

Tags: javascript, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I made a widget for the filab and everytime it gets executed it shows me the following error:

[image]

I got that error a few times before, it always was a syntax error in my code.
But by now ( I think they updated the filab last days) the filab catches this errors, too, and shows where the error is.So this time there must be another problem.

Does somebody else got such a problem and knows how to solve it?

Code in main.js

[image: main.js code]

the callback function is implemented in the main.js, too.

Code in config.xml

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireCloud is complaining about an input endpoint identified as "INPUT2", while you are providing us the code you use for registering "INPUT1".

There is another strange thing, you are registering the callback using this line:

```
MashupPlatform.wiring.registerCallback("INPUT1", callback(this));
```

I'm guessing the correct line is:

```
MashupPlatform.wiring.registerCallback("INPUT2", callback);
```

Or:

```
MashupPlatform.wiring.registerCallback("INPUT2", callback.bind(this));
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the error for the Endpoint 1, too, but I won't promise it (Of course I deleted the version of the widget, so I couldn't check that up)

I don't know that I need to use it in this, way, I will try it out.

Comment: Thats the solution, now I got an error which I could understand ( ;-) ) 
Thanks!